# Gulp deprecated returns "`-- (empty)" on npm ls gulp-util

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I have been trying to compile my Vue assets to run for some time now and it has refused due to one error or the other, I updated my node and npm to stable and latest versions respectively, but yet I have run into a gulp problem.

I just tried to **NPM install**  and it gave this error

> npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5

As the steps required in the medium post above i tried to  n**pm ls gulp-util**

but it returned a **`-- (empty)**

How do I go forward from here
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may because you made a global installation with `-g` .

So please try `npm ls -g gulp-util` instead .

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and I'm still getting -- (empty)